# C#: Array.CreateInstance: Unable to cast object of type [*] to type []

Tags: c#

I want to create a non zero lower bound one dimensional array in c# by calling

```
Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new int[] { length }, new int[] { lower });
```

The type of the returned array is not int[], but int[*].  Can anyone elaborate on what does this mean?  I want to be able to return this array to the caller, for example,

```
int[] GetArray() { ... }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you seeing `int[*]`?  When I run that code I get an array of `int`s.

Comment: D Stanley, at     Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new int[] { 6 }, new int[] { 6 }).GetType().FullName

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use `new int[length]`?  It's shorter, the standard syntax people use, and works...

Comment: Because `int[length]` would be 0-based and the OP explicitly stated she wanted a non-zero based array.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this is a gotcha!

There's a difference between a *vector* and a 1-dimensional array. An `int[]` is a **vector**. A vector (like an `int[]`) ***must*** be 0-based. Otherwise, you have to call it `Array`. For example:

```
// and yes, this is doing it the hard way, to show a point...
int[] arr1 = (int[]) Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), length);
```

or (noting that this is still zero-based):

```
int[] arr2 = (int[]) Array.CreateInstance(typeof (int),
      new int[] {length}, new int[] {0});
```

If your array can't be 0-based, then sorry: you have to use `Array`, not `int[]`:

```
Array arr3 = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int),
      new int[] { length }, new int[] { lower });
```

To make it even more confusing, there's a difference between:

```
typeof(int).MakeArrayType() // a vector, aka int[]
typeof(int).MakeArrayType(1) // a 1-d array, **not** a vector, aka int[*]
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't find the actual code to verify, but experimenting that syntax seems to indicate a one-dimensional array with a non-zero base.

Here's my results:

```
0-Based 1-D Array :        "System.Int32[]"
Non-0-based 1-D Array:     "System.Int32[*]"
0-based 2-D Array :        "System.Int32[,]"
Non-0-based 2-D Array :    "System.Int32[,]"
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is one-dimensional array, than this should do the trick

```
Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), length)
```

When you specify lowerBound, then returning type if quite different

```
var simpleArrayType = typeof(int[]);

var arrayType = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 10).GetType();
var arrayWithLowerSpecifiedType = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 10, 5).GetType();

Console.WriteLine ( arrayType == simpleArrayType ); //True
Console.WriteLine ( arrayWithLowerSpecifiedType == simpleArrayType ); //False
```